# Select just two fields from database using Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know the best practice to recover from database just two fields of an Entity using Spring Data JPA.

Basically, I want to avoid to recover the full entity object in the call.

Should I create a specific class with those two fields?
Is there any way to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

*Should I create a specific class with those two fields?*

yes, this is one of the cleanest ways to achieve the same.

You can use projections from Spring Data JPA [(doc)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). In your case, create interface:

```
interface ProjectIdAndName{
    String getId();
    String getName();
}
```

and add following method to your repository

```
List<ProjectIdAndName> findAll();
```

Otherwise you can follow below native query approach if you want to go by query.

You can set `nativeQuery = true` in the `@Query` annotation from a `Repository` class like this:

```
public static final String FIND_PROJECTS = "SELECT projectId, projectName FROM projects";

@Query(value = FIND_PROJECTS, nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findProjects();
```

Note that you will have to do the mapping yourself though. It's probably easier to just use the regular mapped lookup like this unless you really only need those two values:

```
public List<Project> findAll()
```

It's probably worth looking at the Spring data [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) as well.